# Java - Performing calculations on all of input

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to square all of the numbers on the same line of input, at the moment I have the below code. 
This scans the user input, squares the number and then adds it to an array list. Once the while loop breaks the array list is printed to the user. 
However, when I enter more than one int (seperated by a space) the scanner is only reading the first.

```
while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
        int result = 0;
        int num = scanner.nextInt();
        if(num > 0){
            result += num * num;
        }
        numbers.add(result);

        scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Play again? Enter 'Y' or 'N'");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        if (input.equals("N")) {
            break;
          }
}
```

So for example..

> I/O: 5 5 5
>
> Number stored in array list: 25
>
> Should be: 75

Comment: You also seem to not read properly, as after reading an `int` you call `scanner.nextLine`

Comment: You're calling `scanner.nextLine()` and printing new prompt immediately after reading the first integer. You need to read all numbers first.

Comment: @Eran I'm not sure that is causing the problem.

Comment: also, adding numbers to the array list does not add them arithmetically. it just appends another number to the list.

Comment: @Eran true - but I don't think moving it outside the loop will make any difference?

Comment: @notyou true, that's not the only issue. There should probably be some inner loop that reads the integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter numbers: ");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    try {
        final long sum = Arrays.stream(input.split("\\s+"))
            .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
            .reduce((left, right) -> left * right)
            .getAsLong();
        System.out.println("Result: " + sum);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Only enter numbers!");
    }
    System.out.println("Play again? Enter 'Y' or 'N'");
    if (scanner.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

This will produce:

```
Enter numbers: 5 5 5
Result: 125
Play again? Enter 'Y' or 'N'
n
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfect! please could you tell me how this works?

Comment: Sure. Is there a specific part you're interested in? In general, it reads a line, splits it by space, sums the values and then reads the "continue prompt" line and starts again if it's not `n`.

Comment: yes from 'final long sum' to 'only enter numbers' i'm not sure what each line of code is doing!

Comment: Arrays.stream(input.split("\\s+")) - split the line by spaces, mapToLong(Long::parseLong) - attempt to convert every token to a number, reduce((left, right) -> left * right) - multiply results, getAsLong() - get the number out, since the method returns an Optional<Long>

Comment: This is not doing what was asked. It's returning 5*5*5 instead of (5*5)+(5*5)+(5*5).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to read each number from the user input, and split it into an `array`, and then loop through said `array` and total up the results.

```
do {
            int result = 0;
            String userNumbers = scanner.nextLine();
            String words[] = userNumbers.split(" ");
            for (String word : words) {
                result += Integer.parseInt(word) * Integer.parseInt(word);
            }
            numbers.add(result);
            System.out.println("Play again? Enter 'Y' or 'N'");
            input = scanner.nextLine();
        } while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("N"));
```

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/NFJaFm)

Comment: thanks for this answer it works! how can I avoid using a for loop here?